# Flutter ParagraphBuilder.addText repetitive crashes

Tags: flutter, dart, crashlytics, flutter-text

I released a new version of my app and I just keep getting users having repetitive crashes for this one error. The stack trace does not point to any lines in my code. Just Flutter libraries, I was wondering if anyone has come across this?

It is also only affecting iOS devices. Any help is much appreciated.

#### Error Log

```
# Crashlytics - Stack trace
# Platform: apple
# Version: 2.2.0 (104)
# Issue: 7c4bfab47bc2207ed4ed1e135241743e
# Session: b08d2b7e6fce44569604445ace3a3121_DNE_0_v2
# Date: Tue Jan 24 2023 22:47:14 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)

Fatal Exception: FlutterError
0  ???                            0x0 ParagraphBuilder.addText (dart:ui)
1  ???                            0x0 TextSpan.build + 277 (text_span.dart:277)
2  ???                            0x0 TextPainter._createParagraph + 614 (text_painter.dart:614)
3  ???                            0x0 TextPainter.layout + 662 (text_painter.dart:662)
4  ???                            0x0 RenderParagraph._layoutText + 635 (paragraph.dart:635)
5  ???                            0x0 RenderParagraph._layoutTextWithConstraints + 658 (paragraph.dart:658)
6  ???                            0x0 RenderParagraph.performLayout + 771 (paragraph.dart:771)
7  ???                            0x0 RenderObject.layout + 2135 (object.dart:2135)
8  ???                            0x0 RenderBox.layout + 2418 (box.dart:2418)
9  ???                            0x0 RenderPositionedBox.performLayout + 451 (shifted_box.dart:451)
10 ???                            0x0 RenderObject.layout + 2135 (object.dart:2135)
11 ???                            0x0 RenderBox.layout + 2418 (box.dart:2418)
12 ???                            0x0 RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout + 120 (proxy_box.dart:120)
13 ???                            0x0 RenderObject.layout + 2135 (object.dart:2135)
14 ???                            0x0 RenderBox.layout + 2418 (box.dart:2418)
15 ???                            0x0 RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout + 292 (proxy_box.dart:292)
16 ???                            0x0 RenderObject.layout + 2135 (object.dart:2135)
17 ???                            0x0 RenderBox.layout + 2418 (box.dart:2418)
18 ???                            0x0 _RenderListTile._layoutBox + 1160 (list_tile.dart:1160)
19 ???                            0x0 _RenderListTile.performLayout + 1201 (list_tile.dart:1201)
20 ???                            0x0 RenderObject.layout + 2135 (object.dart:2135)
21 ???                            0x0 RenderBox.layout + 2418 (box.dart:2418)
22 ???                            0x0 RenderPadding.performLayout + 249 (shifted_box.dart:249)
23 ???                            0x0 RenderObject.layout + 2135 (object.dart:2135)
24 ???                            0x0 RenderBox.layout + 2418 (box.dart:2418)
25 ???                            0x0 RenderPadding.performLayout + 249 (shifted_box.dart:249)
26 ???                            0x0 RenderObject.layout + 2135 (object.dart:2135)
27 ???                            0x0 RenderBox.layout + 2418 (box.dart:2418)
28 ???                            0x0 RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout + 120 (proxy_box.dart:120)
29 ???                            0x0 RenderObject.layout + 2135 (object.dart:2135)
30 ???                            0x0 RenderBox.layout + 2418 (box.dart:2418)
31 ???                            0x0 RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout + 120 (proxy_box.dart:120)
32 ???                            0x0 RenderObject.layout + 2135 (object.dart:2135)
33 ???                            0x0 RenderBox.layout + 2418 (box.dart:2418)
34 ???                            0x0 RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout + 120 (proxy_box.dart:120)
35 ???                            0x0 RenderObject.layout + 2135 (object.dart:2135)
36 ???                            0x0 RenderBox.layout + 2418 (box.dart:2418)
37 ???                            0x0 RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout + 120 (proxy_box.dart:120)
38 ???                            0x0 RenderObject.layout + 2135 (object.dart:2135)
39 ???                            0x0 RenderBox.layout + 2418 (box.dart:2418)
40 ???                            0x0 RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout + 120 (proxy_box.dart:120)
41 ???                            0x0 RenderObject.layout + 2135 (object.dart:2135)
42 ???                            0x0 RenderBox.layout + 2418 (box.dart:2418)
43 ???                            0x0 RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout + 120 (proxy_box.dart:120)
44 ???                            0x0 RenderObject.layout + 2135 (object.dart:2135)
45 ???                            0x0 RenderBox.layout + 2418 (box.dart:2418)
46 ???                            0x0 RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout + 120 (proxy_box.dart:120)
47 ???                            0x0 RenderObject.layout + 2135 (object.dart:2135)
48 ???                            0x0 RenderBox.layout + 2418 (box.dart:2418)
49 ???                            0x0 RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.insertAndLayoutChild + 493 (sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:493)
50 ???                            0x0 RenderSliverList.performLayout.advance + 241 (sliver_list.dart:241)
51 ???                            0x0 RenderSliverList.performLayout + 283 (sliver_list.dart:283)
52 ???                            0x0 RenderObject.layout + 2135 (object.dart:2135)
53 ???                            0x0 RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout + 149 (sliver_padding.dart:149)
54 ???                            0x0 RenderSliverPadding.performLayout + 386 (sliver_padding.dart:386)
55 ???                            0x0 RenderObject.layout + 2135 (object.dart:2135)
56 ???                            0x0 RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence + 516 (viewport.dart:516)
57 ???                            0x0 RenderViewport._attemptLayout + 1600 (viewport.dart:1600)
58 ???                            0x0 RenderViewport.performLayout + 1507 (viewport.dart:1507)
59 ???                            0x0 RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize + 1973 (object.dart:1973)
60 ???                            0x0 PipelineOwner.flushLayout + 999 (object.dart:999)
61 ???                            0x0 RendererBinding.drawFrame + 513 (binding.dart:513)
62 ???                            0x0 WidgetsBinding.drawFrame + 884 (binding.dart:884)
63 ???                            0x0 RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback + 378 (binding.dart:378)
64 ???                            0x0 SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback + 1175 (binding.dart:1175)
65 ???                            0x0 SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame + 1104 (binding.dart:1104)
66 ???                            0x0 SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame + 1015 (binding.dart:1015)

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x1eea8 FIRCLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 184
1  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x1f288 FIRCLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1176
2  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x164d4 FIRCLSHandler + 48
3  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x10934 FIRCLSExceptionRecordOnDemand + 1328
4  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x10374 FIRCLSExceptionRecordOnDemandModel + 228
5  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x1e674 -[FIRCLSOnDemandModel recordOnDemandExceptionWithModel:] + 68
6  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x1e0d0 -[FIRCLSOnDemandModel recordOnDemandExceptionIfQuota:withDataCollectionEnabled:usingExistingReportManager:] + 164
7  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x2c268 -[FIRCrashlytics recordOnDemandExceptionModel:] + 140
8  Runner                         0xbe144 -[FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin recordError:withMethodCallResult:] + 177 (FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.m:177)
9  Runner                         0xbda00 -[FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] + 101 (FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.m:101)
10 Flutter                        0x577cd0 (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
11 Flutter                        0x43de4 (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x1e6c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x3a30 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x11f48 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x11b98 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
16 CoreFoundation                 0x51800 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
17 CoreFoundation                 0xb704 __CFRunLoopRun + 2532
18 CoreFoundation                 0x1ebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
19 GraphicsServices               0x1374 GSEventRunModal + 164
20 UIKitCore                      0x514648 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100
21 UIKitCore                      0x295d90 UIApplicationMain + 364
22 Runner                         0x720c main + 5 (AppDelegate.swift:5)
23 ???                            0x104be1ce4 (Missing)

com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x14a0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1ae4 mach_msg + 76
2  CoreFoundation                 0x6d30 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3  CoreFoundation                 0xb1bc __CFRunLoopRun + 1180
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1ebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5  Foundation                     0x19464 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 236
6  Foundation                     0x5ae2c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 92
7  UIKitCore                      0x48e770 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 524
8  Foundation                     0x6943c __NSThread__start__ + 808
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19ac _pthread_start + 148
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe68 thread_start + 8

com.google.firebase.crashlytics.on.demand
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1a2c __semwait_signal + 8
1  libsystem_c.dylib              0x50e4 nanosleep + 220
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x19388 sleep + 52
3  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x1e36c __107-[FIRCLSOnDemandModel recordOnDemandExceptionIfQuota:withDataCollectionEnabled:usingExistingReportManager:]_block_invoke + 340
4  Foundation                     0x51c1c __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
5  Foundation                     0x63f94 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 104
6  Foundation                     0x3c214 __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__ + 24
7  Foundation                     0x4d5dc -[NSOperation start] + 788
8  Foundation                     0x50c68 __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__ + 24
9  Foundation                     0x5ee10 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x12830 _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 148
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x3a30 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
12 libdispatch.dylib              0xb124 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 668
13 libdispatch.dylib              0xbc80 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 392
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x16500 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x10bc _pthread_wqthread + 288
16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe5c start_wqthread + 8

io.flutter.1.ui
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x14a0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1ae4 mach_msg + 76
2  CoreFoundation                 0x6d30 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3  CoreFoundation                 0xb1bc __CFRunLoopRun + 1180
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1ebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5  Flutter                        0x2f90cc (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
6  Flutter                        0x2f8acc (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19ac _pthread_start + 148
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe68 thread_start + 8

io.flutter.1.raster
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x14f4 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x4048 _dispatch_sema4_timedwait + 64
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x463c _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 76
3  QuartzCore                     0x32cc8 -[CAMetalLayer nextDrawable] + 880
4  Flutter                        0x580cc4 (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
5  Flutter                        0x3d31dc (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
6  Flutter                        0x3d3b80 (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
7  Flutter                        0x2f76b0 (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
8  Flutter                        0x3d2f90 (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
9  Flutter                        0x3d4ba4 (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
10 Flutter                        0x3d3e8c (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
11 Flutter                        0x3ddc34 (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
12 Flutter                        0x2f5ec4 (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
13 Flutter                        0x2f91fc (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
14 CoreFoundation                 0xae678 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
15 CoreFoundation                 0x32654 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1064
16 CoreFoundation                 0x2ce00 __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 320
17 CoreFoundation                 0xb4b0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1936
18 CoreFoundation                 0x1ebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
19 Flutter                        0x2f90cc (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
20 Flutter                        0x2f8acc (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
21 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19ac _pthread_start + 148
22 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe68 thread_start + 8

io.flutter.1.io
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x14a0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1ae4 mach_msg + 76
2  CoreFoundation                 0x6d30 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3  CoreFoundation                 0xb1bc __CFRunLoopRun + 1180
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1ebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5  Flutter                        0x2f90cc (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
6  Flutter                        0x2f8acc (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19ac _pthread_start + 148
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe68 thread_start + 8

io.worker.1
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x8298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236
2  libc++.1.dylib                 0xd28c std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28
3  Flutter                        0x2f3840 (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19ac _pthread_start + 148
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe68 thread_start + 8

io.worker.2
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x8298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236
2  libc++.1.dylib                 0xd28c std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28
3  Flutter                        0x2f3840 (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19ac _pthread_start + 148
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe68 thread_start + 8

io.worker.3
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x8298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236
2  libc++.1.dylib                 0xd28c std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28
3  Flutter                        0x2f3840 (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19ac _pthread_start + 148
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe68 thread_start + 8

io.worker.4
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x8298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236
2  libc++.1.dylib                 0xd28c std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28
3  Flutter                        0x2f3840 (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19ac _pthread_start + 148
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe68 thread_start + 8

io.worker.5
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x8298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236
2  libc++.1.dylib                 0xd28c std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28
3  Flutter                        0x2f3840 (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19ac _pthread_start + 148
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe68 thread_start + 8

io.worker.6
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x8298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236
2  libc++.1.dylib                 0xd28c std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28
3  Flutter                        0x2f3840 (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19ac _pthread_start + 148
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe68 thread_start + 8

dart:io EventHandler
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x2e18 kevent + 8
1  Flutter                        0x4e432c (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
2  Flutter                        0x513414 (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19ac _pthread_start + 148
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe68 thread_start + 8

com.google.firebase.crashlytics.MachExceptionServer
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x14a0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1ae4 mach_msg + 76
2  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x18a50 FIRCLSMachExceptionServer + 108
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19ac _pthread_start + 148
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe68 thread_start + 8

com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x14a0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1ae4 mach_msg + 76
2  CoreFoundation                 0x6d30 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3  CoreFoundation                 0xb1bc __CFRunLoopRun + 1180
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1ebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5  CFNetwork                      0x27823c _CFURLStorageSessionDisableCache + 60032
6  Foundation                     0x6943c __NSThread__start__ + 808
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19ac _pthread_start + 148
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe68 thread_start + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe54 start_wqthread + 254

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1a74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1108 _pthread_wqthread + 364
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe5c start_wqthread + 8

DartWorker
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x82c4 _pthread_cond_wait + 1280
2  Flutter                        0x62a8fc (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
3  Flutter                        0x66b9a0 (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
4  Flutter                        0x62a224 (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19ac _pthread_start + 148
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe68 thread_start + 8

DartWorker
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x82c4 _pthread_cond_wait + 1280
2  Flutter                        0x62a8fc (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
3  Flutter                        0x66b9a0 (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
4  Flutter                        0x62a224 (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19ac _pthread_start + 148
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe68 thread_start + 8

DartWorker
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x82c4 _pthread_cond_wait + 1280
2  Flutter                        0x62a8fc (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
3  Flutter                        0x66b9a0 (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
4  Flutter                        0x62a224 (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19ac _pthread_start + 148
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe68 thread_start + 8

DartWorker
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x82c4 _pthread_cond_wait + 1280
2  Flutter                        0x62a8fc (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
3  Flutter                        0x66b9a0 (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
4  Flutter                        0x62a224 (Missing UUID 3adbf2891ee63561a26df1652313df7e)
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19ac _pthread_start + 148
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe68 thread_start + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1a74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1108 _pthread_wqthread + 364
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe5c start_wqthread + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe54 start_wqthread + 254
```

[image]

Comment: facing same on android

Comment: were you able to reproduce/resolve?

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused when we try to use **subString** on a string that contains emoticons and used the result in **Text Widget**. Moreover at an exact char position where we spilt & emoticon exists. Using `runes` and `fromCharCodes` method we can fix the error

**Solution**:

```
String runeSubstring(String input, int start, int end) {
    
    if (input.runes.toList().length > end)
      return String.fromCharCodes(input.runes.toList().sublist(start, end));
    else
      return String.fromCharCodes(
          input.runes.toList().sublist(start, input.runes.toList().length));
  }
```

Error is reproducible by following string

```
String x = "   hi firu   ";
```